# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE difference in Clients

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I am trying to run this query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/myfile.txt"
 IGNORE INTO TABLE mydb.mytable
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

If I run it in MySQL Workbench (v8.0.16) I get an error

**Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version**

However if I run it in SQLYog (Professional v12.09) it works fine.

I am running both bits of code using the same computer, with the same user, on the same database running on the same server.

That server has local_infile = 1

As far as I can tell the only difference in these queries is the SQL Client being used.

My assumption is that it is the connection string / settings that is different between the two as a default, however I can't find any documentation on this.

Why would this be and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In linux you have to start mysql client in command line as.

```
mysql -u root -ppassword --local-infile=1
```

you should also set local_infile = 1 in configuration file